# CSV in Excel Table in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm trying to input CSV information into a table in Excel but I don't know how, it would also help if I could create the table in a python script as well as reading in the CSV file in the same script. Please help.

Comment: Look into http://www.python-excel.org/ and the python module [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Why do you not import  the csv-file into excel with standard excel import features?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` can be very helpful:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
df.to_excel(excel_file_path)
```

This is using some default parameters, you might need to provide some info to [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) depending on how your csv file looks and what output you are expecting.

Comment: How would i go about formatting a table do you know?

Comment: @Shaneyg8 CSVs offer very limited flexibility in terms of formatting. The raw data is just separated by commas.

Comment: @Shaneyg8 Formatting is best done with an excel module for Python. That or you could do it using Excel features itself. You want to make the Excel file first.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) before and I find it to be extremely useful for this purpose. We can help you out more if you tell us exactly what you need. (Install it with `pip` or download from the Internet)

Example code:

```
import csv
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook(write_only = True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
with open("myfile.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ws.append(line)
wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

Other answers are [here](https://superuser.com/a/301451/451250) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684679/4871483)