# Converting csv to Excel via shell script during mailing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following code

```
   awk test1 > out.xsl
 mail -a out.xsl "Test Subject" abc@gmail.com < /dev/null
```

> So I have a file in csv format and i need to convert it into excel
>   when the mail is being sent. I do receive the mail but it gets
>   corrupted when I try to open it. Test1 is a CSV file and Iam converting
>   it in excel file named out.xsl.  Iam sending the excel file in mail but Iam not able to open it or view anything inside it Please help

Comment: excel files are "zipped xml" files so renaming a csv into xls will not make it an excel file. Keep it in csv format, excel can handle it directly. Another way is to convert it by excel itself before the send

Answer (score 0):

Use `unoconv`:

```
unoconv -i FilterOptions=9,,76 -f xls  tables.csv
```

Here 9 is a tab symbol used as field delimiter, and 76 is a codepage (UTF-8).

(`unoconv` doesn't support `xlsx`, only `xls`).

Or write a simple python script with the use of `xlsxwriter`: example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx).

Answer (score 0):

> This script convert all csv to xlsx format

```
for f in *.csv; do 
mv -- "$f" "${f%.csv}.xlsx"
done
```

It convert all files in the folder

Comment: This script doesn't convert anything, it just renames files.

Comment: you are correct but it works to open file in microsoft excel ..  .xlsx is nothing but csv for msexcel

Answer (score 0):

try

```
unix2dos -o test1
```

use

- -o to change file in place
- -n to create a new file

then email the file as attachment and open in excel

```
 mail -a out.xsl "Test Subject" abc@gmail.com < /dev/null
```