# Writing a sheet name that differs from filename when webscraping

Tags: python

I am scraping a table from a website and writing it to a csv file.  The name of the file is correct, however I need the name of the sheet within the workbook to be "Raw_Data", rather than the file name.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import re
import datetime


html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KNYSENEC1#history/tdata/s20171104/e20171104/mdaily").read().decode('utf8')
json_data = re.findall(r'pws_bootstrap:(.*?)\s+,\s+country\:', html, re.S)
data = json.loads(json_data[0])

nnow = datetime.datetime.now().date()
Filenamee = "seneca_weather_" + str(nnow)
filename = ('%s.csv' % Filenamee)
f = open(filename, "w")

for days in data['history']['days']:
    for obs in days['observations']:
        f.write(str(obs['date']['iso8601']) + "," + str(obs['temperature']) + "," + str(obs['pressure']) + "," + str(obs['wind_dir']) + "," + str(obs['wind_speed']) + "," + str(obs['precip_today']) + "\n")
```

I'm very new to both python and webscraping so sorry for the super broad question.  Thanks

Comment: So you want to change the name of the `csv` sheet name? Cause `csv`s don't have sheet names, `excel` just displays the file name in the workbook as the sheet name.

Comment: To do that look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684679/3407256

Answer (score 0):

Great to see you are trying Python. As soon as you work with tables I recommend the pandas library. Check out the docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/.

Here you have an answer using pandas and json_normalize.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import re
import datetime
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KNYSENEC1#history/tdata/s20171104/e20171104/mdaily").read().decode('utf8')
json_data = re.findall(r'pws_bootstrap:(.*?)\s+,\s+country\:', html, re.S)
data = json.loads(json_data[0])

nnow = datetime.datetime.now().date()
filename = "seneca_weather_{}.xlsx".format(nnow)

df = json_normalize(data['history']['days'])

cols = ["summary.date.iso8601","summary.temperature", 
        "summary.pressure","summary.wind_dir",
        "summary.wind_speed","summary.precip_today"]

df[cols].to_excel(filename,index=False,sheet_name=filename)
```

Output:

[image: excel screenshot]

If you want it in *.csv simply do:

```
df[cols].to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```