# How to export data from textedit to excel file using python 3

Tags: python, excel, export, pyqt5, textedit

Today I have a new problem so I hope that everybody can help me. My problem is export data from textedit to excel file using python 3. I had found many documents but all of them can not help me. Please give me some helps :)

Comment: I guess you are looking for converting your file into an excel
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx

Comment: No, I don't. I want to save text to excel file. The text is recognize from image. I use pytesseract library to recognize text, it includes name, phone number, email, website then I have to save the text to excel file like: Name: abc, Phone number: 0123, Email: example@gmail.com

Comment: This is an image about my prject https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5QgO.png

Comment: Before trying to save the information in an excel you must separate the information where you have Name, Phone Number, Email separately since as I assume the images that you process do not have an established format.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is regular, then the problem will be simple.

For example:
If every line has":",you can catch it with regular expressions":".
Then, Insert the character before and after the colon into a dictionary.

something like:
`{date:2017-11-16, time:17:09, ......}`

finally， use xlrd and xlwt.

you can easily export data from python dictionary to excel using xlrd and xlwt.

---

But, if your data is random.
It's too difficult, and I don't have a good way,either.

Comment: my project is use ocr to recognize text from image, the text is Vietnamese, then I have to save the text to excel file like: fullname: abc, phone number: 01234,...