# is there a Faster way to write or read in/to with pandas data frame with about 1 million row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, spyder

I am trying to be really specific about my issue. I have a dataframe with some 200+ columns and 1mil+ rows. I am reading or writing it to a excel file which takes more than 45 mins if I recorded right.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data_file.csv", low_memory=False, header=0, delimiter = ',', na_values = ('', 'nan'))
df.to_excel('data_file.xlsx', header=0, index=False)
```

My question- is there anyway we can read or write faster to a file with pandas dataframe because this is just one file example. I have many more such files with me

Comment: Try using [xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx) to convert your file directly from .csv to .xlsx.

Comment: @theodoros: no no my purpose is different I have to do processing and modelling on data too that is just for example for reading and writing.

Comment: Checkout feather. If it can be used for application it will optimize your task greatly

Comment: can you describe a little about feather please

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

- Investigate [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/), which provides a Pandas like `DataFrame` that can distribute processing of large datasets across multiple CPUs or clusters. Hard to say to what degree you will get a speed up, if your performance is purely IO bound, but certainly worth investigating. Take a quick look at the [Dask use cases](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html) to get an understanding of its capabilities.
- If you are going to repeatedly read the same CSV input files, then I would suggest converting these to HDF, as reading HDF is orders of magnitude faster than reading the equivalent CSV file. It's as simple as reading the file into a `DataFrame` and then writing it back out using `DataFrame.to_hdf().` Obviously this will only help if you can do this conversion as a once off exercise, and then use the HDF files from that point forward whenever you run your code.

Regards,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

That is a big file you are working with. If you need to process the data then you can't really get around the long read and write times.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT write to xlsx, use csv, writing to xlsx is taking long time. 
Write to csv. It takes a minute on my cheap laptop with SSD.

Comment: I dont think that would solve my problem. I have business requirement.