# How to keep one column with numbers as string in xlsxwriter while converting csv to xlsx?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, xlsxwriter

I'm using script from here [convert-csv-to-xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx) to do the conversion with little modification (I add several arguments including **'strings_to_numbers': True** ):

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx',  {'constant_memory': True, 'strings_to_urls': False, 'strings_to_numbers': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
                print(r)   
    workbook.close()
```

Everything works fine but as I've added the above mentioned argument I'm getting all the numbers as numbers in my xlsx files. I need to keep one column (first) as a string as there are long numbers which convert (due to excel number length limitation) to something like this **1,04713E+18** [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBPpK.png)

Maybe i need to remove the argument and convert the needed columns from strings to numbers at the end. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Workbook](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html?highlight=Workbook) documentation. `strings_to_numbers` converts `string` to `float`. There is no parameter that converts `string` to `int`. Therefore, you need to make conversion manually.

Instead of doing `worksheet.write(r, c, col)`. You need to do [`worksheet.write_number(r, c, col)`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_number). Also, you need to convert `col` to `int(col)`.

Number can be checked by regexp or any other method.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.