# how to coy the content/data from ( .csv)csv file to (.xlsx)excel file using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsx, xls, xlwt

how to coy the content/data from csv file to excel file using python3?

> how to coy the content/data from csv file to excel file using python3?

```
how to coy the content/data from csv file to excel file using python3?
```

Comment: Please someone help me

Comment: Excel can import CVS files directly.

Comment: please explain with the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert csv to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx)