# Selenium - Save XLS file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I would like to make `selenium` automatically download `.xls` file on Ubuntu 20.04 (firefox) without that annoying pop-up.
I'm using this setting for `.csv` file which works

```py
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/suomi422")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

but for the .xls files i tried with this settings

```py
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

which doesn't works...

this is how the pop-up looks like.

[POP-UP Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKgU2.png)

Comment: the same file is downloading as `csv` but not as `xls` ?

Comment: i dont know the solution to make it download as `xls` , but if you're able to download the file you want in `csv` format , i would recommend you to just convert that `csv` to `xls` file from python code itself .

Comment: for converting `csv` to `xls` you could try this i guess - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58896073/6490744