# Python - ERROR: lib_type = fields[4] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I Have written a small script for converting a text file into an excel spreadsheet by splitting the lines by "|". But I am getting a List index out of range error for lib_type = fields[4]. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

**My code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import xlwt 
from xlwt import Workbook

    
file = open("apk_library_other.txt","r")

wb = Workbook()                     #create spreadsheet
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
ctr = 0

for line in file:
  fields = line.split("|")
  app_name = fields[0] 
  apk = fields[1]
  lib_name = fields[2]
  lib_type = fields[3]   
  lib_permission = fields[4]

  sheet1.write(ctr, 0, app_name)  
  sheet1.write(ctr, 1, lib_name)  
  sheet1.write(ctr, 2, lib_type)  
  sheet1.write(ctr, 3, lib_permission)
  ctr += 1
  #print(app_name + lib_name + lib_type)

wb.save('libraries_other.xls') 
file.close()
```

**text file being read:**

```
com.carenity.carenity_2020-07-16.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.DUMP
com.carenity.carenity_2020-07-16.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
com.carenity.carenity_2020-07-16.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
DiseasesDictionaryTreatments.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.BACKUP
DiseasesDictionaryTreatments.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

Comment: give me content of "apk_library_other.txt"

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Each line has 3 `|` symbols. So the size of `fields` is 4. So the last index is `3`. You can't access `4`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert csv to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to access an element in the list that does not exist results in an `IndexError`. The following solution worked on my end.

**text.txt**

```
com.carenity.carenity_2020-07-16.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid| android.permission.DUMP 
com.carenity.carenity_2020-07-16.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS 
com.carenity.carenity_2020-07-16.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
DiseasesDictionaryTreatments.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.BACKUP 
DiseasesDictionaryTreatments.apk|Google Mobile Services|Development Aid|android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

**Solution**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'text.txt', 
    sep='|',  # separate by pipe
    names=['apk', 'lib_name', 'lib_type', 'lib_permission']
)

# save to csv
df.to_csv('converted_text.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rows in the text file that you have shared only have **four** columns but you are trying to access `fields[4]` which is the **fifth** column.