# How to read data from multiple csv files and write into same sheet of single Excel Sheet in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want append multiple csv files data into same sheet of single excel sheet with one empty row between data.

1.csv

```
ID  Currency    Val1    Val2        Month
101 INR     57007037.32 1292025.24  2021-03
102 INR     49171143.9  1303785.98  2021-02
```

2.csv

```
ID  Currency    Val1    Val2        Month
103 INR     67733998.9  1370086.78  2020-12
104 INR     48838409.39 1203648.32  2020-11
```

Now I want to write into same sheet of excel sheet with one empty row like below.

output.xlsx

```
ID  Currency    Val1    Val2        Month
101 INR     57007037.32 1292025.24  2021-03
102 INR     49171143.9  1303785.98  2021-02

103 INR     67733998.9  1370086.78  2020-12
104 INR     48838409.39 1203648.32  2020-11
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert csv to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx)

Comment: Your csv need to be right delimited (comma, semicolon, ...) without extra spaces, quoted or not, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.csv:

```
ID;Currency;Val1;Val2;Month
101;INR;57007037.32;1292025.24;2021-03
102;INR;49171143.9;1303785.98;2021-02
```

2.csv:

```
ID;Currency;Val1;Val3;Month;Year
103;INR;67733998.9;1370086.78;2020-12;2020
104;INR;48838409.39;1203648.32;2020-11;2020
```

3.csv

```
ID;Currency;Val2;Year
105;INR;34325309.92;2020
106;INR;18098469.39;2020
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs = []
files = ["1.csv", "2.csv", "3.csv"]

for csv in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, delimiter=";")
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN] * df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns))
    dfs.append(df)

dfs = pd.concat(dfs).to_excel("output.xlsx", na_rep="", index=False)
```

[image]

**Edit**: problem of columns order

```
>>> df
    2019-01   2020-01   2020-09  ...   2021-03  2021-03.1   Name  id  currency
0  0.665912  0.140293  0.501259  ...  0.714760   0.586644    Ram   A       INR
1  0.217433  0.950174  0.618288  ...  0.699932   0.219194  Krish   A       INR
2  0.419540  0.788270  0.490949  ...  0.315056   0.312781  Sandy   A       INR
3  0.034803  0.335773  0.563574  ...  0.580068   0.949062  Dhanu   A       INR
```

```
>>> BASECOLS = ["id", "currency", "Name"]
>>> cols = BASECOLS + list(reversed(df.columns[~df.columns.isin(BASECOLS)]))
>>> df[cols]
  id currency   Name  2021-03.1   2021-03  ...  2020-09   2020-01   2019-01
0  A      INR    Ram   0.586644  0.714760  ...  0.501259  0.140293  0.665912
1  A      INR  Krish   0.219194  0.699932  ...  0.618288  0.950174  0.217433
2  A      INR  Sandy   0.312781  0.315056  ...  0.490949  0.788270  0.419540
3  A      INR  Dhanu   0.949062  0.580068  ...  0.563574  0.335773  0.034803
```

Comment: @ corralien, I'm getting error NameError: name 'np' is not defined.

Comment: @ corralien, Now I'm getting error NameError: name 'dfs' is not defined and also my source csv files are delimited by '\t' space.

Comment: @ corralien, Thanks for your kind help !!

I have made some changes and here is the full code for some one.

Comment: @ corralien, Below answer is perfectly working when all csv files columns are same and not working when columns are different.

Request your help when we have different columns.

Comment: I don't understand it works for me. What's the error? I will update my post soon.

Comment: @ corralien, I'm getting in reverse order. attached the screenshot in question. Please help on this !!

Comment: Is it just a problem of columns order (or a problem with the column `2021-03.1`)?

Comment: @ Corralien, It is not problem with 2021-03.1.It is problem with columns order only. Order should be Id, currency, Name, 2020-03, 2020-03.1, 2020-02, 2020-01, 2019-12.

Comment: @ Corralien, Thank You so Much !!...Can you please put all code lines in single snippet.

Comment: No, I can't sorry because answers need two input data types (not same columns names, data format). I use purposely `df` as variable name so you can integrate easily the second snippet code into the loop of the first answer. You have to adapt the code a bit to suit your needs.

Comment: @ corralien, It's Ok....I observed that data got reversed when writing into excel sheet. Is there any way to re reverse the data when writing data into excel ?? Any help ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231665/discussion-between-corralien-and-rummy).

Answer (score 0):

[The `pandas` package](https://pandas.pydata.org/) makes this much easier in my opinion:

```
import pandas as pd

files = [
    'path/to/file1.csv',
    'path/to/file2.csv',
    'path/to/file3.csv',
]


spreadsheet = pd.ExcelWriter('path/to/output.xlsx')

for file in files:
    sheet_name = file.split('.')[0]
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    data.to_excel(spreadsheet, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=None)

spreadsheet.save()
```

Comment: @ jfaccioni, I have updated mu question. Please help on this.

Comment: @Rummy you should open a new question rather than update an old question. It makes the existing answers obsolete for anyone that searches this topic in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use to use pandas. It has an excellent xlsx writer thant can do the job for you very simple.
Basically you have to initialize your excel writer then loop through csvs, read one by one and write to file. I suggest you to use `pd.ExcelWriter` so xlsx file will be touched only one time. Also `mode='a'` lets you append sheets to existing excel file, remove it if you want to overwrite the entire file.
See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

```
import pandas as pd
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    #here you loop through csvs and load
    for csv in csvs:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

try:

    spreadsheet = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/Report.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/'):
        final_data=pd.DataFrame()
        for csv in files:
            df = pd.read_csv(csv)
            df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns) 
            final_data=final_data.append(df) 
            final_data=final_data.append(df1)
            final_data.to_excel(spreadsheet,na_rep="",sheet_name='report',index=False)
    
    spreadsheet.save()

except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
        print("Unable to load data into Excel Sheet")
        raise
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!