# How to unpivot dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-melt

I have a dataset which I need to unpivot into multiple rows into columns.

Eg:

```
ID  Currency    Val1    Val2        Month
101 INR     57007037.32 1292025.24  2021-03
101 INR     49171143.9  1303785.98  2021-02
101 INR     54039073.81 1469727.23  2021-01
101 INR     67733998.9  1370086.78  2020-12
101 INR     48838409.39 1203648.32  2020-11
101 INR     43119693.71 0           2020-10
```

I need to pivot / unpivot them as below.

```
ID  Currency    Keys        2021-03     2021-02         2021-01         2020-12     2020-11     2020-10
101 INR         Val1    57007037.32     49171143.9      54039073.81     67733998.9  48838409.39     4311.71
101 INR         Val2    1292025.24      1303785.98      1469727.23      1370086.78  1203648.32      0
```

I have tried df.melt but that is not the giving exact output.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/abc.csv')
print(df.melt(id_vars=['id'], var_name=['month'], value_vars=['val1','val2']))
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Please don't post images. Edit your question and add your code/dataframes in the text format so that we could be able to copy these while trying to solve your question.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, Edited my question. Please on this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using `.pivot`:

```
print(
    pd.pivot(
        df,
        index=["ID", "Currency"],
        columns="Month",
        values=["Val1", "Val2"],
    )
    .stack(level=0)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "keys"})
)
```

Prints:

```
Month   ID Currency  keys      2020-10      2020-11      2020-12      2021-01      2021-02      2021-03
0      101      INR  Val1  43119693.71  48838409.39  67733998.90  54039073.81  49171143.90  57007037.32
1      101      INR  Val2         0.00   1203648.32   1370086.78   1469727.23   1303785.98   1292025.24
```

---

EDIT: Solution that works in `pandas=0.22.0`:

```
print(
    df.set_index(["ID", "Currency"])
    .pivot(columns="Month")
    .stack(level=0)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "keys"})
)
```

Prints:

```
Month   ID Currency  keys      2020-10      2020-11      2020-12      2021-01      2021-02      2021-03
0      101      INR  Val1  43119693.71  48838409.39  67733998.90  54039073.81  49171143.90  57007037.32
1      101      INR  Val2         0.00   1203648.32   1370086.78   1469727.23   1303785.98   1292025.24
```

---

EDIT: To sort columns:

```
x = (
    df.set_index(["ID", "Currency"])
    .pivot(columns="Month")
    .stack(level=0)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_2": "keys"})
)
x.columns.name = ""
x = x[["ID", "Currency", "keys"] + sorted(x.columns, reverse=True)[3:]]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
    ID Currency  keys      2021-03      2021-02      2021-01      2020-12      2020-11      2020-10
0  101      INR  Val1  57007037.32  49171143.90  54039073.81  67733998.90  48838409.39  43119693.71
1  101      INR  Val2   1292025.24   1303785.98   1469727.23   1370086.78   1203648.32         0.00
```

Comment: I tried yours but getting error - TypeError: pivot_simple() got multiple values for keyword argument 'index;.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.22.0 version.

Comment: @Rummy That's really historical version. Can you upgrade it?

Comment: My organization using this one so i can't able to upgrade. Please let me know some other ways.

Comment: @Rummy I specifically installed `pandas=0.22.0`. See my edit for working solution. But I strongly advise to update the pandas version.

Comment: Thank You So Much !! It's working but I need to display month in desc order i.e 2021-03,2021-02,2021-01,2020-12... And is there any possibility to hide first column i.2 Month

Comment: Perfect, Thank You So Much !!

How to write output data into csv or excel ??

Comment: @Rummy `x.to_csv("filename.csv")`

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely, can you please help on this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530497/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-csv-files-and-write-into-same-sheet-of-single-exc

Comment: @Rummy It's better to open a new question than edit an old one (to prevent confusion). Revert the edit, create a new question and I'll try to look at it.

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely, I tried to open but it is not allowed. Please help !!

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. `stack` and `unstack`

```
(df.set_index(['ID', 'Currency', 'Month']).stack()
  .unstack(-2).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2': 'keys'}))
```

#### 2. `Melt` and `pivot`

```
df.melt(['ID', "Currency", 'Month'], var_name='keys')\
  .pivot(['ID', 'Currency', 'keys'], 'Month', 'value').reset_index()
```

---

```
Month   ID Currency  keys      2020-10      2020-11      2020-12      2021-01      2021-02      2021-03
0      101      INR  Val1  43119693.71  48838409.39  67733998.90  54039073.81  49171143.90  57007037.32
1      101      INR  Val2         0.00   1203648.32   1370086.78   1469727.23   1303785.98   1292025.24
```

Comment: ....your solution looks elegant....any article/link you can suggest where i can have better understanding of stack/unstack and Melt/pivot apart from the documentation..Thanks for any lead...

Comment: Thank you @Deepak i suggest you to check the [official pandas docs of `reshaping`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.htmla) the dataframe which is thoroughly written and will definitely help you understand reshaping the dataframe better.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
>>> df.groupby(["ID", "Currency"]) \
      .apply(lambda x: x[["Month", "Val1", "Val2"]] \
                       .set_index("Month") \
                       .rename_axis(columns="Key") \
                       .transpose())

Month                  2021-03      2021-02      2021-01      2020-12      2020-11      2020-10
ID  Currency Key
101 INR      Val1  57007037.32  49171143.90  54039073.81  67733998.90  48838409.39  43119693.71
             Val2   1292025.24   1303785.98   1469727.23   1370086.78   1203648.32         0.00
```

For Pandas version prior to 0.24, change `rename_axis(columns="Key")` to `rename_axis("Key", axis="columns")`

Comment: I tried your answer but getting error - TypeError: rename_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'.

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account your older version. As @AndrejKesely said, you have to update your version.

Comment: ,can you please look into below one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530497/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-csv-files-and-write-into-same-sheet-of-single-exc

Answer (score 1):

using `set_index` + `unstack` + `stack`:

```
(df.set_index(['ID', 'Month', 'Currency']).unstack('Month')
.stack(level=0).rename_axis(index={None: 'Keys'}).reset_index())
```

---

```
Month ID    Currency  Keys  2020-10     2020-11     2020-12     2021-01     2021-02     2021-03
0     101   INR       Val1  43119693.71 48838409.39 67733998.90 54039073.81 49171143.90 57007037.32
1     101   INR       Val2  0.00        1203648.32  1370086.78  1469727.23  1303785.98  1292025.24
```