# Download xlsx file with Python

Tags: python, excel

Want to download to local directory. This code works for csv but not xlsx. It writes a file but cannot be opened as Excel.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
url = 'https://some_url'
resp = requests.get(url)
open('some_filename.xlsx', 'wb').write(resp.content)
```

Comment: did u check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42703510/6660638? Changing the extension does not mean changing the content inside the file

Comment: I am slightly unclear. Is the file on the server already a .xlsx file (which you can download manually and open from Excel)?

Comment: Yes, source file is already xlsx on server.

Comment: Fwiw, I download files using `urllib`, as `import urllib.request as ur`, then simply `ur.urlretrieve(url, localFile)` to download the file. Perhaps try that and see if the downloaded file is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dataframe from the resp data and then use pd.to_excel() function to obtain the xlsx file. This is a tested solution, and it worked for me.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url='https://www.google.com' #as an example
urlData = requests.get(url).content  #Get the content from the url
dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('latin-1'))) 
filename="data.xlsx"
dataframe.to_excel(filename)
```

Comment: @Patrick_Ng I've updated my comment, because I got to test the proposed solution and it worked. Please, confirm if this has worked for you also.

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` you could just do:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://some_url'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to read directly into dataframe. Need the file for a separate process.