# Getting ec2 details in xlsx format

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am able to get all the ec2 instance details in csv format using boto3.But i am not able to print all the ec2 instance details in xlsx file.

```
enter code here
```

can any one suggest how to print all the ec2 details in the account?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. What script did you use to get the csv format?

If you used create_data_set, you could follow the boto3 documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html?highlight=xlsx).

If your script is working fine for csv files or already have the csv files, then you can just use xlsxwriter or openpyxl as stated in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx).

And honestly once you have csv files, you can simply open in a spreadsheet software like microsoft excel and use the 'save as' operation.